# Combining hex bytes into a string in VBA, without losing the leading Zero?

Tags: excel, vba, hex, byte

In VBA, I am trying to select 4 bytes out of a hex array, and convert them to decimal. However, if the byte is smaller than F, the first digit, which is 0, is lost in the compilation of the  string, and the conversion is thus wrong.

I have tried various solution on this forum, without success.

The string I need to convert looks like this variable (called measHex):
    AA 00 00 22 00 03 00 00 1F 07 00 BC 07

I am trying to convert bytes 7 to 10, to look like this:
    00001F07

but what I get is 1F7

The following code is my function.

```
Private Function ToHexStringMeas(ByRef measHex As Variant) As String
    ReDim bytes(LBound(measHex) + 6 To LBound(measHex) + 9)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(measHex) + 6 To LBound(measHex) + 9
        bytes(i) = Hex(measHex(i))
    Next
    ToHexStringMeas = Strings.Join(bytes, "")
End Function
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify what you want.  You write *... concert them to decimal* but no where in your code are you doing that.  And you write *… I am trying to convert bytes 7 to 10, to look like this: `00001F07`*  but  `00001F07` is not a decimal number.  And your `Join` function is using a space as a delimiter, but the value you show as a result does not include any spaces!  Also, it is not clear what value you are passing to your function (what is `measShoot`?) to let it know you only want bytes 7-10.

Comment: To be technically correct, "Hex" converts the hex number to decimals, which are then printed as strings. Updated question slightly to clarify, but I already figured it out by myself. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Here `Hex` converts a decimal number to Hex.  As you can see where `Hex(12) --> C`.  To convert `AA 00 00 22 00 03 00 00 1F 07 00 BC 07` to `00001F07` can be done without VBA using just string functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more research, the solution was to add some code as follows:

```
Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(measHex) + 6 To LBound(measHex) + 9
        bytes(i) = Hex(measHex(i))

        Dim l As Integer 

        l = 2

        h(i) = Replace(Space(l - Len(Hex(measHex(i)))), " ", "0") & Hex(measHex(i))

    Next
    ToHexStringMeas = Strings.Join(h, "")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also accomplish what I think is your goal using string functions.

**VBA**

```
Function ToHexStringShoot(ByRef measHex As String, Optional first As Long = 7, Optional last As Long = 10) As String
    ToHexStringShoot = Replace(Mid(measHex, (first - 1) * 3, last * 3 - (first - 1) * 3), " ", "")
End Function
```

**Worksheet Formula** *using the same logic*

```
=SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,6*3,10*3-6*3)," ","")
```